# how do I get ubuntu to recognize/mount my intel 180 GB ssd on /dev/sdb?

Tags: ssd

I have installed INTEL 330 series 180 GB SSD in my Dell Tower inspiron 530S.  The BIOS sees this HD as SATA#5.  However my operating system is Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and no other OS on computer.  GParted identifies an unrecognized, unallocated partition of correct size on /dev/sdb.  I was able to get gparted to put DOS file system in place?  But I am unable to do anything with the ssd.  I assume that it wants to be mounted to be recognized.  GParted says it does not know where/how to do that.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: "I was able to get gparted to put DOS file system in place?" - Was this on purpose or you didn't know which file system to use?, format it to ext4.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What is your current situation and what are you trying to accomplish? Do you have an Ubuntu installation on another drive already or are you trying to install Ubuntu on the SSD now? Do you want to migrate it to your SSD or do you just want to use the drive with a file system on a current installation?

Comment: What is your current situation and what are you trying to accomplish? My current situation is that I have ubuntu only as my desktop OS with one SATA HD in the computer.  what are you trying to accomplish? I have now added the SSD and want to put the Ubuntu OS on that drive for increased speed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to partition the disk, format the partitions, and then they can be mounted in Ubuntu.

Aside from that, it seems Ubuntu is seeing the disk just fine, as you were able to see it in GParted.